# Low graphic (800x600); Graphic card support; Reinstall? (after Upgrade 16.04 LTS)

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, radeon, fglrx

I have recently upgraded to 16.04 (from 14.04). Since then, the system is running on low graphics (800x600, built in display). 
I assume the best advise to be  reinstalling Ubuntu 16. But the question is, as I see the graphical problems now, does 16.04 LTS even support my Radeon graphic cards (hybrid or one) properly? Or should I reinstall Ubuntu 14 and going back to fglrx-driver (btw, even there only one graphic card worked properly)? Is there another solution?

> 00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. >[AMD/ATI] Kabini [**Radeon HD 8330**] [1002:9832]
>   Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Kabini [Radeon HD 8330] [1043:148d]
>   Kernel modules: radeon
>
> 01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] >Sun XT [**Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430**] [1002:6660]
>   Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] [1043:21fd]
>       Kernel modules: radeon

xrandr

> xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
>   Screen 0: minimum 800 x 600, current 800 x 600, maximum 800 x 600
>   default connected primary 800x600+0+0 0mm x 0mm
>     800x600       75.00*

Comment: I'm sorry for interrupting you. Just because you said there could be something left from fglrx I naively ran the "purge fglrx - command". It seems, that there were something left and now I have high resoluton.  I thaught the upgrade would deinstall fglrx automatically?  - Anyway, I appreciate your advice, thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same, because 16.04 doesn't have this package. Well, seems we were wrong. I think you can now answer you own question :) Congratulations!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64781/discussion-on-question-by-t-doe-low-graphic-800x600-graphic-card-support-re).